# generate date feature column using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a timeseries data frame that has columns like these:

```
Date          temp_data        holiday           day   

01.01.2000    10000              0                1
02.01.2000    0                  1                2
03.01.2000    2000               0                3
..
..
..
26.01.2000    200                0                26
27.01.2000     0                 1                27
28.01.2000    500                0                28
29.01.2000     0                 1                29
30.01.2000    200                0                30
31.01.2000     0                 1                31
01.02.2000     0                 1                 1
02.02.2000    2500               0                 2
```

Here, holiday = 0 when there is data present - indicates a working day

holiday = 1 when there is no data present - indicated a non-working day

I am trying to extract three new columns from this data -*second_last_working_day_of_month* and *third_last_working_day_of_month* and the *fourth_last_wday*

the output data frame should look like this

```
Date          temp_data   holiday     day     secondlast_wd   thirdlast_wd    fouthlast_wd

01.01.2000    10000         0          1             1                0              0
02.01.2000    0             1          2             0                0              0
03.01.2000    2000          0          3             0                0              0
..
..
25.01.2000    345           0          25            0                0              1
26.01.2000    200           0          26            0                1              0
27.01.2000     0            1          27            0                0              0
28.01.2000    500           0          28            1                0              0
29.01.2000     0            1          29            0                0              0
30.01.2000    200           0          30            0                0              0
31.01.2000     0            1          31            0                0              0
01.02.2000     0            1          1             0                0              0
02.02.2000    2500          0          2             0                0              0
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
data = [['26.01.2000', 200, 0, 26], ['27.01.2000', 0, 1, 27], ['28.01.2000', 500, 0, 28], 
        ['29.01.2000', 0, 1, 29], ['30.01.2000', 200, 0, 30], ['31.01.2000', 0, 1, 31], 
        ['26.02.2000', 200, 0, 26], ['27.02.2000', 0, 0, 27], ['28.02.2000', 500, 0, 28],['29.02.2000', 0, 1, 29]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'temp_data', 'holiday', 'day'])
```

`df`

```
    Date        temp_data   holiday day
0   26.01.2000  200         0       26
1   27.01.2000  0           1       27
2   28.01.2000  500         0       28
3   29.01.2000  0           1       29
4   30.01.2000  200         0       30
5   31.01.2000  0           1       31
6   26.02.2000  200         0       26
7   27.02.2000  0           0       27
8   28.02.2000  500         0       28
9   29.02.2000  0           1       29
```

---

**Code**

for example make `secondlast_wd` column (n=2)

```
n = 2
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
result = df['holiday'].eq(0) & df.iloc[::-1, 2].eq(0).groupby(s.dt.month).cumsum().eq(n)
```

`result`

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
8    False
9    False
Name: holiday, dtype: bool
```

make result to `secondlast_wd` column

```
df.assign(secondlast_wd=result.astype('int'))
```

output:

```
    Date        temp_data   holiday day secondlast_wd
0   26.01.2000  200         0       26  0
1   27.01.2000  0           1       27  0
2   28.01.2000  500         0       28  1
3   29.01.2000  0           1       29  0
4   30.01.2000  200         0       30  0
5   31.01.2000  0           1       31  0
6   26.02.2000  200         0       26  0
7   27.02.2000  0           0       27  1
8   28.02.2000  500         0       28  0
9   29.02.2000  0           1       29  0
```

you can change `n` and can get third, forth and so on..

---

**Update for comment**

chk workday(reverse index)

```
df.iloc[::-1, 2].eq(0) # 2 means location of 'holyday'. can use df.loc[::-1,"holiday"]

9    False
8     True
7     True
6     True
5    False
4     True
3    False
2     True
1    False
0     True
Name: holiday, dtype: bool
```

reverse cumsum by group(month). then when workday is +1 above value and when holyday is still same value with above.(of course in reverse index)

```
df.iloc[::-1, 2].eq(0).groupby(s.dt.month).cumsum()


9    0
8    1
7    2
6    3
5    0
4    1
3    1
2    2
1    2
0    3
Name: holiday, dtype: int64
```

find holiday == 0 and result == 2, that is secondlast_wd

```
df['holiday'].eq(0) & df.iloc[::-1, 2].eq(0).groupby(s.dt.month).cumsum().eq(2)
```

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
8    False
9    False
Name: holiday, dtype: bool
```

This operation returns index as it was.(not reverse)

---

**Other Way**

A more understandable code would be:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
idx1 = df[df['holiday'].eq(0)].groupby(s.dt.month, as_index=False).nth(-2).index
df.loc[idx1, 'lastsecondary_wd'] = 1
df['lastsecondary_wd'] = df['lastsecondary_wd'].fillna(0).astype('int')
```

same result

Comment: Can you add comments to the result? if possible

Comment: Can we add `df.iloc[::-1,"holiday"]` ? because my dataframe has many columns it is difficult to change the number every time a new column is added or deleted.

Comment: then must use loc instead iloc like: `df.loc[::-1,"holiday"]` you can use like this. but I don't want to edit answer.

Comment: Thanks I will change accordingly. you don't have to edit the answer

Comment: @Bella_18 The first answer is more concise and the way I use it (I avoid inplace)

It seemed difficult to understand, so I added a second method that was easier to understand.

Comment: This code works good but if I have data for 2 years then it is only working for last year - My data starts from October 2020 to  12 November 2022 -- And the result is produced only from November 2021. Can you help me on how to solve this. I think it is because of grouping by month